# A consequence of a $C^{1}$ function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ being negative-definite.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**I was working on the following problem**

> Let $f=(f_{1}, \ldots, f^{n})$ map an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be $C^{1}$ and suppose that for some $\bar{x} \in U$ the matrix $f'(\bar{x})$ is negative definite. Show that there is a positive number $\epsilon$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $\bar{x}$ such that if $y_{1}, \ldots , y_{n}$ are any $n$ points in $V$ and if $A$ is the $n \times n$ matrix whose $i$-th row is $\bigtriangledown{f^{i}(y_{i})}$, then $\xi^{T}A{\xi} \leq -\epsilon \vert \xi \vert^{2}$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**I have the following rough idea, but I am having trouble turning it into an argument**

One could argue by contradiction that suppose that
$$(\forall \epsilon >0)(\forall B_{\delta}(\bar{x})(\exists y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n} \in B_{\delta}(\bar{x}))(\exists \zeta \in S^{n-1})$$ where if $A$ is defined as above then $$\zeta^{T}A\zeta \geq -\epsilon$$.

The idea I have is the following:

What I want to do is make $\epsilon$ "small" so small that we essentially have that 
 $$\zeta^{T}A\zeta \geq 0$$
I also want to make $\delta$  "small"  so that we essentially have that $A \approx f'(\bar{x})$ and a contradiction. **I'm not sure how to do this.**

What's confusing is that the matrix $f'(\bar{x}): \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the matrix of a bounded linear operator and is hence continuous but it is continuous with respect to $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ not with respect to the point $\bar{x}$.

**Any help on this problem would be appreciated**

Comment: But that $f$ is assumed $C^1$ means that $x \mapsto f'(x)$ is continuous on $U$.

Comment: So the map that is continuous is the map $f': U \rightarrow Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n})$? The space $Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n})$ has a metric induced by the operator norm is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And you should be able to make your argument precise. I would prefer a direct argument, though. Since $M := f'(\overline{x})$ is negative definite, there is a $c > 0$ with $\xi^TM\xi \leqslant -c\lvert\xi\rvert^2$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now take the continuity of $(\xi,A) \mapsto \xi^TA\xi$ and the continuity of $f'$ to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I posted an answer based on the direct argument you gave me. I sincerely thank you for your help again. It cleared away lots of confusion for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expansion of the argument by Daniel Fischer in the comments.

We set $M := f'(\bar{x})$. Since $M$ is negative definite, we have that
$(\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0})( \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n})$ we have that
$\xi^{T}M\xi \leq c \| \xi \|$.

We can define a map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \hom(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that sends $(\xi, A) \mapsto \xi^{T}A\xi$. If we fix $\xi$, we have that this map is linear with respect to $A$, hence it must be bounded and consequently continuous.

We make the observation that $f$ is $C^{1}$ which means that the map $f': U \rightarrow \hom(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n})$ that sends $p \mapsto f'(p)=df_{p}$ is continuous. In particular, we have that the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_{j}}}(p)=df_{p}(\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x_{j}}})$$
are continuous on $U$.

If we define the matrix $A$ as in the question above, then we have 
$$(A-M)_{ij}=\frac{\partial{f^{i}}}{\partial{x_{j}}}(y_{i})-\frac{\partial{f^{i}}}{\partial{x_{j}}}(\bar{x})$$
hence we can make $\|A-M \|$ as "small" as we'd like. In particular, for any $\delta>0$, we cat fine $\eta>0$ where if $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n} \in B_{\eta}(\bar{x})$ then $\|A-M \| < \delta$.

Since the map $(B, \xi) \mapsto \xi^{T}A\xi$ was continuous with respect to $A$, it is continuous at $M$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$ where $\vert \xi^{T}A\xi -\xi^{T}M\xi \vert < \epsilon$. We can find $\eta$ based on what, we said above, we can find $B_{\eta}(\bar{x})$, where choosing $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n} \in B_{\eta}(\bar{x})$ and defining $A$ as above, we indeed have $\|A-M \| < \delta$ and  hence $\vert \xi^{T}A\xi -\xi^{T}M\xi \vert < \epsilon$
which implies that

$$\xi^{T}A\xi < \xi^{T}M\xi+ \epsilon \leq c \vert \xi \vert^{2}$$